# PHP altetrnative way how to timeout

Tags: javascript, php, timeout

i am making a tool where user can provide a delay time of response. It should be easy to do however when I used `set_time_limit` from [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

> Warning: set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons

From error and by googling a bit it's obvious that hosting provider disable this functionality in PHP.

**Question:**
However I want to ask you if there is some alternative way how to timeout response using php without this function.

I can imagine this can be done via pass this timeout value to JS and timeout it via that but I hope if there isn't some other soluction for this.

Comment: Do you want to set a maximum timeout on a request, or do you want to wait before executing certain PHP code?

Comment: This is good point Randy, I just realize that I don't need to stop execution just want to wait before display data to user. I just used `sleep()` for it and it works great

Comment: I just wanted to paste the url of the sleep library :P

Answer (score 0):

The only idea I had is to put in your script some "waypoints" where you check the execution time, and if the execution time is too long terminate the script using `die()`, to check the execution time you can use `new DateTime("now");` at every "waypoint" and then something like `$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);` to get the interval between the first time you had and the last one